# Illegal pattern character 'O' in SimpleDateFormatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'O'
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:845)

when executing this code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MON-YY");
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"DD-MON-YY"` is not a valid date format. Try:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details of valid formats.

Answer (score 1):

Your logs are self explainatory,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'O'
java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:845)
java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:659)
```

Read the first line itself.
The SimplDateFormat accepts pattern following are some examples.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Reference - https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/java-dateformat-example/

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving a correct date format. For example, you could do:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")
```

but not

```
new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MON-YY");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the Oracle date and time format specifiers are not fully supported by SimpleDateFormat. You should either change this pattern, or find a way (implement a function) to convert it to SimpleDateFormat supported pattern.